# How to get a list of variables that a function is a function of?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

Suppose i have:

```
import sympy  as sp

theta = sp.S('theta')
u = sp.S('u')

X = sp.Function('X')(theta,u)
```

How do I get a list out of `X` that contains the variables `u` and `theta`?
So: `X.SomeMethodOrFunc()` results in `[theta,u]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `free_symbols` works, the more direct request is `.args` which will (for any SymPy object that has them) return the object contained within the object. In the case of a Function, the arguments are literally what you see:

```
>>> Function('f')(x,y).args
(x, y)
```

For other things, there may be more returned

```
>>> IndexedBase('A')[x,y].free_symbols
{A, A[x, y], x, y}
```

Answer (score 1):

`X.free_symbols` will do what you want, but you'll need to convert the resulting set to list:

```
>>> import sympy as sp
>>> theta = sp.S('theta')
>>> u = sp.S('u')
>>> X = sp.Function('X')(theta,u)
>>> X.free_symbols
{theta, u}
>>> list(X.free_symbols)
[theta, u]
```

Comment: That is exactly what I need!